# Vue js and scss or Sass

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, sinon

I'm more into refactoring so having style inside the same file as my html irks me.

I don't want to use `<style>` html tags filled with css that are intertwined with my functions & methods in every component.

I want to keep using sass or scss files. (a single file that is my own + bootstrap and other general purpose scss files that I pick up on the web).

how do I do this?

I've tried :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import './assets/scss/App.scss' <- this is the line I added that broke the app.

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

inside my main.js

but I got a 404 error :

[image: 404 not found]

UPDATE :

looked at this : [What is the difference between linking stylesheets and requiring them in Webpack + VueJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194155/what-is-the-difference-between-linking-stylesheets-and-requiring-them-in-webpack) curious if I should switch to using a link? I tried it but I don't know where I should put it.

I should specify that I'm starting from this scaffolding : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

SECOND UPDATE :

I've been following the guide at : https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9

Comment: Does "require('./assets/scss/App.scss')" work?

Comment: @Wouter no :( ...

Comment: Both work fine for me, can't reproduce :l (I also used the vue-cli)

Comment: see updated OP, tell me if knowing where I'm starting from helps.

Comment: SACC or SCSS files needs compiler, how will you compile them on runtime?

Comment: I'm adding webpack as a compiler (I don't know the terminology, is webpack what you mean?) I'm having issue there as well. I'm making another post asking how to add webpack to a vue.js project.

Comment: Your import seems to be pretty fine. I guess the error lies in your webpack config. Did you set up a scss loader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a less popular (and for whatever reason not well documented) way to include a link in your single-file components:

```
</script>

<style src="./assets/scss/App.scss"></style>
<style>
  /* Your component styles go here */
</style>
```

Simple and effective, in my opinion! : )

**Edit**: I should mention that since Webpack has to load this file, then you should select the "Use Sass" option when setting up with **vue-cli**.

**Edit 2**: Steps to set up a project from scratch with built-in Sass/SCSS support:

- In your directory where you'd like to place the new project, run:
  `vue init webpack-simple your-dir-name`
- Follow through the prompts *carefully* and note that the fourth option (after `author`) asks "Use sass? (y/N)"
- Type in `y`
- Your project now has sass configured for webpack! :)

And if you forgot to do that for an existing project, you can cheat from here:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Soooo close!!!! Yes! I did forget to do that. and even with your helpful code it still does not load my scss.
here's my build/webpack.base.conf.js : https://pastebin.com/GAgwR0Ha
I've done a bunch of things to this end : my package.json got `"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0"`

Comment: but your talk of a simple option during set up of "use sass" sounds amazing!  I want that option. how do I start from scratch in a way that makes me encounter this prompt?

Comment: I edited my answer so it'd be easier to read than a comment (what with the syntax highlighting involved)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of importing it in the `javascript` part, switch it to import from `css` part... I know that you:

> I don't want to use  html tags.

But I assume that you mean that you want the `compiled` css instead of plain css. You can try this way:

```
<style lang="sass">
    @import '../assets/scss/App.scss';

    .others_css_classes {
      ...
    }
 </style>
```

And add in the `build/wepack.base.conf.js` config file the part:

```
{ 
   test: /\.scss$/, 
   loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ] 
 },
```

It's a mix from the [link](https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9) you shared and I extracted a part of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308180/vue-js-webpack-vue-loader-bootstrap-sass-sass-loader?rq=1)

If you installed the Vue from vue-cli you should (automatically) have the webpack installed in the /build (if you used the official webpack template).

Hope it helps!

Comment: that sounds great the issue is the scaffolding's loader I linked does not start out handling scss files. how would I go about upgrading it? I have a stackoverflow for this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914294/how-to-add-webpack-3-8-1-to-a-vue-project