# How to add Webpack 3.8.1 to a Vue project

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

say I've go this scaffolding : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

I want to add Webpack 3.8.1 to it.

there's already a "build" folder with lots of webpack files in it :

[image: webpackfiles]

but (one of) the issue(s) is running "webpack" in the project's root returns :

[image: webpackfails]

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ this si the doc I'm supposed to go by.

there's no real example.

it's got :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
  }
};
```

which I adapted to the best of my ability to :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(entry, 'dist'),
    filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
  }
};
```

I also added a entry.js file containing nothing under src :

[image: file tree with entry.js]

and I edited my package.json file to include:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
```

and ran :

```
npm install
npm update
```

I feel I'm getting somewhat close but I still cannot manage to use the new webpack.

Comment: I think that your problem is to try to use `webpack`, you should use the npm run script like: `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, and then the vue+webpack will do the work for you, placing the files where the config says (webpack.base.dev.conf for instance).

Comment: yeah you can answer that it's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my comment as answer to be able to close this question and (hopefuly) help others future users.

I think that your problem is to try to use `webpack`, you should use the `npm run` script like: `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, and then the `vue+webpack` will do the work for you, placing the files where the config says (`webpack.base.dev.conf` for instance).

If you take a look at package.json, you could see this part:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
```

Every one can be executed with `npm run X`.

Hope it helps!